# Can't bind data to a custom attribute of a custom view

Tags: java, android

I created a custom text view that attach an audio guidance to text.

```java
public class AudioGuidanceTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    private String originalText;
    private static final String buttonPosition = "[PLAY]";
    private int audioId;
    private boolean hasAudio;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    private ImageSpan playButton;
    private ImageSpan stopButton;

    public AudioGuidanceTextView(Context context, @NonNull AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        TypedArray attrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.AudioGuidanceTextView);
        hasAudio = attrs.getBoolean(R.styleable.AudioGuidanceTextView_hasAudio, true);
        if (!hasAudio)
            return;
        audioId = attrs.getResourceId(R.styleable.AudioGuidanceTextView_audioFile, -1);
        originalText = getText().toString();

        Drawable playButtonDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_audio_play_button);
        Drawable stopButtonDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_audio_stop_button);
        playButtonDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, playButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), playButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        stopButtonDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, stopButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), stopButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        playButton = new ImageSpan(playButtonDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        stopButton = new ImageSpan(stopButtonDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

        setSpannableString(false);
    }

    // some methods...

}
```

This view class takes a custom attribute that refers to a raw audio file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AudioGuidanceTextView">
        <attr name="audioFile" format="reference" />
        <attr name="hasAudio" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The following is an example. This view works perfectly well in this example.

```xml
<com.myapp.customview.AudioGuidanceTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:audioFile="@raw/some_audio_file"
    android:text="@string/some_string"
    android:textColor="@color/blueGray"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Next, I tried binding an int data to this `audioFile` attribute.

```xml
<com.myapp.customview.AudioGuidanceTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColor="@color/noticeGray"
    android:text="@string/WHAT_BUTTONS"
    android:visibility="@{vm.succeededStage == 3 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
    app:audioFile="@{vm.buttonAudio}" />
```

```java
@Bindable
public int getButtonAudio() { return buttonAudio; }
```

In this case, Android Studio could not build my app, which is the issue here..

```
[databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a setter for \u003ccom.myapp.customview.AudioGuidanceTextView app:audioFile\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027int\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/dialog_success_stage.xml","pos":[{"line0":136,"col0":29,"line1":136,"col1":42}]}
```

I tried to find if there is any case similar to mine, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: That error means that it can't find a `setAudioFile(int)` method in your `AudioGuidanceTextView` class. Attributes with binding expressions in the layout XML do not get processed in the `View`'s constructor like classic attributes. The binding framework is translating them into simple `object.setAttributeName(…)` calls – just like you would have to write if you weren't using binding – and it can't find a setter for your custom attribute to call after the object has been constructed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mike. As I understood from your comment, in the successful case(the one where I didn't use binding but referred to the raw file directly), the app called the constructor of `AudioGuidanceTextView`. However, when I used binding, the app tried to find `@BindingAdapter("audioFile")` but it couldn't. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Right, a method marked `@BindingAdapter("audioFile")`, or just a method named `setAudioFile()`. In either case, you need some method in `AudioGuidanceTextView` to set that value after construction. I think it checks for the explicit method first, and then the annotation, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I think I should clarify: `AudioGuidanceTextView`'s constructor is being called in both cases. However, in the second case, at build time, the binding framework sees that `app:audioFile="@{vm.buttonAudio}"` has a binding expression for its value, so it strips that attribute from the `<AudioGuidanceTextView>` tag and writes the setter code for it instead. The `app:audioFile="@{vm.buttonAudio}"` attribute doesn't actually exist at runtime in the second case.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you again! I think I'm figuring it out. So, directly assigning a value to an attribute in a layout file and data binding work in two entirely different way. The former delivers the value in an `AttributeSet` parameter to the constructor of the view object. The latter calls the setter method after the view object constructed.  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Exactly. Data binding is a relatively new addition to Android development, and it had to be built on top of the existing `View` framework, so it has some odd, nonobvious behavior for a few things.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! It helped a lot. Now I can work to resolve this thanks to your help